# No identa el código automáticamente al pulsar enter

Tags: netbeans

Hola es la primera vez que instalado `netbeans` y tengo un problema a la hora de pulsar **enter** para escribir mi siguiente instrucción.

Lo que sucede es que al pulsar **enter** la linea comienza al inicio del programa y no lo identa automaticamente. Para poder identar, tengo que hacerlo con la **barra espaciadora**. ¿Es que `netbeans` trabaja así?. Yo he trabajado con otros programas y si lo identa automaticamente.

Adjunto el código como queda al darle enter.

```
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Main.java to edit this template
 */
package vista;

/**
 *
 * @author Irbin
 */
public class Ejercicio01 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
int a=5;
double k=2.5;

        // TODO code application logic here
DESDE AQUIE COMIENZA LA IDENTACION
Y LE DOY ENTER Y ENTER Y NO IDENTA
         Y TENGO QUE HACERLO CON LA BARRA DE
         ESPACIO TANTAS VECES COMO SEAN NECESARIAS

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Prueba lo que sugieren en este link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311912/how-do-i-autoindent-in-netbeans#:~:text=To%20format%20all%20the%20code,%2B%20Shift%20%2B%20left%20arrow%20key.&text=I%20have%20netbeans%206.9.

Answer (score 0):

Si pulsas <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (Windows) se te identará todo el documento

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/334824)